# iOS: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not being called even with shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, orientation, screen-orientation

I have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    NSLog(@"shouldRotate");
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"Hello there");

    [self.webpage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

}
```

But in my log "hello there" never appears, even though "shouldRotate" does.

My setup is so that I have a TabBarController with 4 regular View Controllers inside of them. This tab in particular just has a WebView inside of it. When I shift the orientation simply nothing happens.

Should I be doing something at the AppDelegate level?

Could someone help me understand whats going on?

Comment: What do you return in the other 3 view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not called on popViewControllerAnimated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595471/willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-not-called-on-popviewcontrolleranimate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to animate rotation with TabBarController, ViewControllers on all Tab bars should return YES for supported orientation.

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is just place, where you can configure this setting.