# How to rearrange programmatically created view on rotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

`ViewControllerA` has a method `viewDidLoad` that programmatically creates a button like:

```
self.cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(330, 625, 125, 30);
[self.cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.cancelButton sizeToFit];
[self.cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.cancelButton setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view addSubview:self.cancelButton];
```

I also have `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{return YES;}`.

When the device is rotated to landscape, I want to change the button frame. I've tried checking `interfaceOrientation` in my `shouldAutorotate...` method above and setting the frame. I've tried doing `if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])` and resetting the frame there. None of this has worked. Any suggestions?

EDIT

Here's another attempt that produces no change:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
  self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 300, 50);
  } 
}
```

So I tried doing:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
  || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    NSLog(@"Portait");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Landscape");
  }
}
```

And neither of the NSLogs get called, ever. My view is rotating though...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this from UIViewController:

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

Take a look at this post:
[willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not called on popViewControllerAnimated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595471/willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-not-called-on-popviewcontrolleranimate)

Comment: I added an edit with an attempt. I also tried `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` with that same code, but no change to the UI.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method to make sure it's called with the proper value? I seem to remember also that if you have multiple controllers on the screen at one time, things get goofy, especially on iOS < 5

Comment: I just added an update to the original post. `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` is never getting called in my code even though the view IS rotating. Your comment about multiple controllers on screen is interesting though as the viewcontroller I'm trying to work on right now is controlling this view which is a `modalPresentationStyle UIModalPresentationFormSheet` view. Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: Updated my response with a link to a similar post. Yes, multiple controllers may be the problem, or at least causing the wrong controller to be notified.

Comment: I just tried putting the `willAnimate..` method in my presentingViewController and it is now getting rotation information. I set my cancelButton to be a public property in my .h file of the other controller and I can now update it's frame. I'm going to try the link you posted as I think that's a better solution if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check the orientation thus....

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
|| interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
 {
  // portrait & upsidedown
  self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(330, 625, 125, 30);
 }
 else
 {
    // landscape
    self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(330, 625, 125, 30);
 }
}
```