# IOS Orientation not changing after back from another controller

Tags: ios, uiimage, orientation

i'am newbe in IOS development and it's my first app dealing with different orientations on both iPad and iPhone..

Here is the scenario,
i implement this function to deal with orientation and it's work fine for me.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

But when i go to another page and change the orientation(eg: landscape) and then comeback again to the first page(eg: still in landscape mode), the background of UIImage not change anymore..

I would really appreciate of any answer, thanks

Comment: How do you assign the image to your view?

Comment: hi @AlexSmith i use this to assign the image `UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    UIColor *backgroundPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:backgroundPattern];
`

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating your issue. I created a single view project with storyboards, in which I have 2 views, ViewController1 as the `rootViewController` for a UINavigationController and ViewController2. I only implement the `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and I don't have any issues... Sorry.

Comment: Hi @AlexSmith i forgot to mention you, on top of View i put subview and assign the image as background for container, so the issue is happened here, on this subview..

Comment: So, does the main view change orientation or just the subview?

Comment: Hi @AlexSmith, The main view is work fine, the problem is for subview.

Comment: I still can't reproduce... Sorry chap, [try this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1rgylcf821kwtsn/RlfCRwZjgM)

Comment: Hi @AlexSmith, thank you so much for your assist, [this is](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15112060/abc.zip) what i did in my code, i just edit from your code to show what's the problem

Comment: The code you sent me successfully orients the image. Just check the names of the images in your code. The only problems I see are that the image size, position are off. When in landscape orientation, the image repeats in the x-direction. Use `NSLog(@"self.subview.frame=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.subview.frame));` to check it's coordinates to debug.

Comment: Hi @AlexSmith I've found the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595471/willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-not-called-on-popviewcontrolleranimate), so i just need to implement this code `- (void) updateLayoutForNewOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        // Do some stuff
    } else {
        // Do some other stuff
    }
}` to handling the orientation when back to another controller, thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  [self performSelector:@selector(setImageFrame)];

  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
  }
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  [self performSelector:@selector(setImageFrame)];

  return YES;
  }
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  [self performSelector:@selector(setImageFrame)];

  return YES;
  }

or Just check the autorisizing mask if using xib or set the all Like         lbltitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ....