# iOS view is empty on first run

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiinterfaceorientation

The problem is that, my application will not display the log inside `NSLog` when I first run it. But the text appears by the time I change my orientation to landscape. The default view of the application is portrait by the way.

`viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

But if I do this in my `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.0;

    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

It displays the log without a hitch.

The question is, am I doing the right way to display the log?

My `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:`

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                NSLog(@"iPhone/Portrait");
                break;

            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                NSLog(@"iPhone/Landscape/Left");
                break;

            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                NSLog(@"iPhone/Landscape/Right");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    else {
        switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                NSLog(@"iPad/Portrait");
                break;

            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                NSLog(@"iPad/Upside Down");
                break;

            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                NSLog(@"iPad/Landscape/Left");
                break;

            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                NSLog(@"iPad/Landscape/Right");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check what orientation is sent in `toInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: I added `if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape/Left");
    }
    
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape/Right");
    }
    
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
    }
    
    else {
        NSLog(@"Upside Down");
    }` to `viewDidLoad` and it outputs `Portrait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Scott Roth did the trick: [willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not called on popViewControllerAnimated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595471/willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-not-called-on-popviewcontrolleranimate)

Added `updateLayoutForNewOrientation:`

```
- (void)updateLayoutForNewOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            NSLog(@"Portrait");
        }

        else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            NSLog(@"Landscape");
        }
    }

    else {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            NSLog(@"Portrait");
        }

        else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            NSLog(@"Landscape");
        }
    }
}
```

Changed my `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` to

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

And added `[self updateLayoutForNewOrientation:[self interfaceOrientation]];` to `viewDidLoad:`